# Passing data based on another api response from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an api which will list what all access do the current user have, so once the app.js loads I am calling the api in the componentWillMount, so basically I have three routes , home, userslist, eachuser. So the home is a static text page.

userslist is a component where I list all the users, once you click on the edit icon of user it will take you to the details of the user in the eachuser component.

The problem is since the calls are async once the useraccessApi resolves and gets only the data I should call the usersListApi , by passing the useraccessApi response.

What I mean by happy flow is first user loads the localhost:3000/home so the useraccessApi will call and the redux  have data, so while switching to userslist tab on componenWillMount it will work. But if the user directly selects localhost:3000/userlist it will throw error on componenWillMount so moved the code to componentWillRecieveProps().

So how can I resolve this issue. Or should I use mergeProps to resolve it.

```js
App.js


componenWillMount(){
 this.props.userAccessApi()
}


UsersList

componentWillMount(){
  const {currentUserAccess} = this.props
 // if its a happy flow else it will be currentUserAccess is undefined
 if(currentUserAccess){
   this.props.usersListApi(currentUserAccess)
 } 
}


// inorder to resolve it 

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  const {currentUserAccess} = nextProps
   if(currentUserAccess){
   this.props.usersListApi(currentUserAccess)
   } 
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUserAccess: state.access
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of React Lifecycle events.

For `componentWillMount`
This function is called right before the component’s first render, so at first glance it appears to be a perfect place to put data fetching logic.

But, there’s a “gotcha,” though: An asynchronous call to fetch data will not return before the render happens. This means the component will render with empty data at least once. Which is why your dispatch function fails and you get undefined.

Instead you should use `ComponentDidMount`as the event in which you will fetch data.

By the time `componentDidMount` is called, the component has been rendered once.

In practice, `componentDidMount` is the best place to put calls to fetch data.

Using it makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state properly, so you don’t end up with undefined state that causes errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, since its an async call  the currentUserAccess is undefined . Even in componentDidMount